# Separation the string with comma when occurs "\r\n"

Tags: python, arrays, django, string, django-queryset

I have a string in which there are "\r\n", wants to remove and insert a comma there and have a couple of elements in the array.

This is my code:

```
def test_method(self):
    my_list = self.texts.filter(code='open')
    for i in my_list:
        return strip_tags(i.text.replace('\r\n', ',').split(','))
```

my_list is: `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

I only have one string with commas.

Comment: What is `strip_tags`?.. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the error you're having is that it is only working for the one line.

That is because you're using `return` which will return after the first iteration of your for loop, so you can change `return` to `yield` and this will provide you a generator you can iterate over.

```
for i in my_list:
    yield strip_tags(i.text.replace('\r\n', ',').split(','))
```

Otherwise, if its a list you want to end up with. You need to make a temporary list first

```
ret_val = []
for i in my_list:
    ret_val.append(strip_tags(i.text.replace('\r\n', ',').split(',')))
return ret_val
```

Answer (score 0):

As you require array of elements as final outcome, you can create an array from comma separated string

couple_of_elements_comma_separated_string.split(",")

What are you exactly looking for? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You only get one string because you're doing `return` inside the for loop instead of after. And instead of doing `.append` inside the for loop you can do this with a list comprehension. Assuming your `test_method` otherwise works as intended it would look like this:

```
def test_method(self):
    my_list = self.texts.filter(code='open')
    return [strip_tags(i.text.replace('\r\n', ',').split(',')) for i in my_list]
```

However, if the only thing you want to do is to replace `\r\n` with `,` within your strings, the last row could be simplified to this:

```
return [i.replace('\r\n', ',') for i in my_list]
```